# Getting max() from list of dates using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, datetime

Using Python 3.6.8

I had the below portion of my script working previously on some test data, but now that I've tried to spool it up to the production data, it's not working. This is a snippet of a much larger script, but I believe my error is somewhere in these lines of code below. The field that the SearchCursor is searching is a date type field and every record has a date in it (no nulls/none).

It is looking at a list of dates and should be assessing the 'max' (most recent) but on line 25 it's returning:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and
>   'datetime.datetime'

Here is my pared-down code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime
from datetime import time, timedelta

# Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace =r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"
arcpy.env.scratch = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"

workspace = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb"
ptFC = r"C:\GIS\CAD_reporting\CAD_reporting.gdb\RMI_pts"
dateList=[]
nowDT = (datetime.datetime.today()).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
lowDate = datetime.datetime.today()

# START
print ("Start: " + nowDT)

# Get date for the query start(low date)
dtCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ptFC, "ReportQueryDate")
for row in dtCursor:
    dateList.append(row)
del dtCursor

maxDateTuple = max(dateList) # TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

lowDate = maxDateTuple[0] - timedelta(days=200) # subtracts 200 days
lowDateString = lowDate.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
print (lowDateString)
```

I can tell this error has to do with the data types, but I'm not sure how to handle my variables, to get them into the same/correct format for comparison.

Comment: It looks like you are appending the whole row to `dateList` - are you sure you don't have to reference the specific column or column index of the row to append to the list? e.g. maybe `row["ReportQueryDate"]` or `row[0]`?

Comment: One/some rows must have empty value.

Comment: Indeed: I was mistaken about my data. There were some records with nulls!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that I was wrong about all records in the SearchCursor field having a date value: there was a definition query applied within ArcGIS that was filtering what I saw to only those that had dates. There were, indeed, some hidden records that had NULLs in this field.

They python syntax posted above was correct and does work, assuming all records in the table have a valid date value.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question. However, answering yourself and stating mistakes often is the better choice.